# Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: jar, builder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhWJW.jpg)

Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get immediate help, please be clear what you expect from the community of helpers. Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1. **Disable the offline mode** by visiting File-> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle and **uncheck Offline work**

[image]

2. Make Sure that you are connected to the Internet
3. Go to Build-> Make Project (Ctrl+F9) and let the gradle download the essential files
4. Rebuild the project